# How can I insert the ribbon under the page break everytime?

Tags: excel, vba

The point of this is to print a PDF page for our weekly schedule. C column has the start date for each job and I need a ribbon that takes up the whole row to beak up each day of the week in the schedule. I have a `Do While Loop` that checks C column and adds the ribbon for each new date but since there are multiple pages I also need the ribbon to show under each page break.

The problem I'm running into is that the ribbon doesn't always get inserted under the page break but rather sometimes above it. I found a With Loop that handles the page breaks correctly each time but I don't know how to get it to work with my `Do While Loop`. Basically, I can only either add the day of week ribbon under the page break OUR everytime the date of week changes.

```
Sub forEachDayOfWeek()

    Range("A4").Formula = "=TEXT(C5,""dddd"")"
    Range("E6").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Do While ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) <> "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) <> ""
   If ActiveCell.Value = 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
   ElseIf ActiveCell.EntireRow.PageBreak <> xlPageBreakNone Then
      Rows("4:4").Copy
      Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
      ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -2) Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value > ActiveCell(-1, 0) Then
        Rows("4:4").Copy
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    End If
Loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub forEachPageBreak()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PgBreak As HPageBreak

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    If .HPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then
        For Each PgBreak In .HPageBreaks
            Rows("4:4").Copy
            PgBreak.Location.Insert
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No data in sheets"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

In the picture, I have redacted some information but you can see the list of what I'm talking about. Tuesday is above the page break. Here is an image of the results [image]

Comment: In code you *always* copy 4-th row, but on the screen shot the text is different.

Comment: 4th row has the day of week formula added to it at the beginning of the code _Range("A4").Formula = "=TEXT(C5,""dddd"")"_ I copy/paste this to get all the other rows.

Comment: Could you upload sample workbook to some cloud storage?

Comment: Here is a link to the sample doc. https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ojdtfvhrB0Rnf2l7CVpg4hWe7a8stgM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check the [workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UClAN22vYzcWERhKFi)